# Adding background color for currentvalue animated plotly graph in R

Tags: r, plotly, plotly-dash

In the following code how can i add a bgcolor to the currentvalue parameter?
I have tried to add a color using bgcolor = 'yellow' but it's not working at all.
Is there anyway to achive that?
Here's the full code

```
library(plotly)

x <- seq(0,10, length.out = 1000)

# create data
aval <- list()
for(step in 1:11){
  aval[[step]] <-list(visible = FALSE,
                      name = paste0('v = ', step),
                      x=x,
                      y=sin(step*x))
}
aval[3][[1]]$visible = TRUE

# create steps and plot all traces
steps <- list()
fig <- plot_ly()
for (i in 1:11) {
  fig <- add_lines(fig,x=aval[i][[1]]$x,  y=aval[i][[1]]$y, visible = aval[i][[1]]$visible, 
                   name = aval[i][[1]]$name, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', hoverinfo = 'name', 
                   line=list(color='00CED1'), showlegend = FALSE)
  
  step <- list(args = list('visible', rep(FALSE, length(aval))),
               method = 'restyle')
  step$args[[2]][i] = TRUE  
  steps[[i]] = step 
}  

# add slider control to plot
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(sliders = list(list(active = 3,
                             currentvalue = list(
                               prefix = "Frequency : ",
                               font = list(size = 40, color = "red"),
                               xanchor = "center", yanchor = "top", y = 0,
                               x = 5,  # Adjust the x position
                               pad = list(t = 100)  # Adjust the top padding
                             ),
                             steps = steps)))

fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that's offered via an argument in Plotly. However, you can manipulate the plot after plotting using `htmlwidgets`.

Plotly creates the graph in SVG, text attributes in SVG vary significantly from vanilla HTML. In order to add background color or highlighting, you need to add a filter, a rectangle to fill or a line to surround the text.

In this solution, I've added a filter to the text element.

Without the escapes necessary for R, this is what the filter looks like. The `flood-color` is how you get the yellow background.

```
<defs>
  <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="solid">
    <feFlood flood-color="yellow" result="bg" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="bg"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
  </filter>
</defs>
```

To use this filter, this `def` node precedes the label node. Then the filter is added as an attribute to the label node.

Here's how you can add it to your plot (where nothing changed from the code you used in your question).

If you're not familiar with JS, the content in `/* this here */` are comments. I've added comments in the JS so that you can follow what's happening.

```
fig %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
      "function(el, x) {
        var fltr = '<defs><filter x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" id=\"solid\"><feFlood flood-color=\"yellow\" result=\"bg\" /><feMerge><feMergeNode in=\"bg\"/><feMergeNode in=\"SourceGraphic\"/></feMerge></filter></defs>';
        var wh = 'class=\"slider-label\"';          /* text used for str_replace */
        var nAttr = ' filter=\"url(#solid)\" ';     /* attribute to call the filter */
        var jsp = document.querySelector('#' + el.id + ' g.infolayer > g.slider-container > g');
        var txt = jsp.childNodes[0].outerHTML;      /* collect label node as string */
        txt = txt.replace(wh, wh + nAttr);          /* add call filter to label element */
        jsp.childNodes[0].outerHTML = fltr + txt;   /* replace label node */
      }"
  )
```

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.

[image]

Comment: That's great, Kat, Thanks soo much it's working perfectly now.
But I'm trying to apply it also on another graph in the same way, but it's not working idk what did I miss.
I'm trying to apply it on a graph that has a play button ..  is there any parameter I should know to change if I want to modify or create another graph?

Comment: I made several graphs trying to reproduce this problem. I think I have figured it out. It's not that the code is wrong, the issue lies in timing. It appears that when animation is used, the function runs before the graph is fully loaded, so it can't find the label to change it.  After `function(el, x) {`, add `setTimeout(function(){`, and before the closing `}` (that closes `function(el, x)`), add `}, 200)`. That will cause the code to delay 200 ms after the graph loads. If you have any trouble understanding what I've written here or if it doesn't work, let me know. I can edit my answer.

Comment: wow that's wonderful You did it thanks soo much for your help.
I didn't expect to find a solution for this case.
I really appreciate your help.